# bash IO redirection, how du dup() STDERR?

Tags: bash, io, file-descriptors

Consider the following example:

```
exec 10>&2 # duplicate STDERR to fd 10
{ echo ok; inexistantcommand; } > /tmp/both 2>&1 10>/tmp/err
exec 10>&- # close fd 10
```

I expect /tmp/err to have error, but it's blank:

```
$ cat /tmp/both
ok
-bash: inixistantcommand: command not found

$ cat /tmp/err
$
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

Tried:

```
{ echo ok; qsdfghjk;  } &> >(tee /tmp/both) 2>/tmp/err
```

but /tmp/both have only `STDOUT`

Comment: I don't see any code that writes to fd 10.  If you need to duplicate the data, use `tee`.

Comment: Can you show us please? : Where to place `tee`...

Comment: Or use `zsh` where you can use `{ echo ok; inexistantcommand; } > /tmp/both 2>&1 2> /tmp/err` (where `zsh` does the equivalent of `tee` in a hidden internal process when a fd is redirected several times for writing)

Comment: I'm looking for a bash solution accordingly to my tag

Comment: Added my try: `{ echo ok; qsdfghjk;  } &> >(tee /tmp/both) 2>/tmp/err`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be about duplicating data from a stream rather than duplicating file descriptors.  A data stream is duplicated by `tee`.

```bash
{ echo ok; this is an error; } 2> >(tee err.log) | cat >both.log
```

This would write both the `ok` string and the error message to `both.log`, and would also write the error message to `err.log`.

The error message is duplicated by `tee`, which reads it from its standard input stream, coming from the redirected error stream from the compound command. The `tee` utility writes all its input to the given file(s) and the standard output stream. The standard output of the compound command and of `tee` is piped to `cat`, which writes them to `both.txt`.

Comment: I guess you're using `cat` and a pipe to work around the fact that  bash doesn't wait for `tee`'s termination in `{ { echo ok; this is an error; } 2> >(tee err.log); } > both.log` ?

Comment: Using standard `sh` syntax like `{ { echo ok; tic is an error; } 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | tee err.log 3>&-; } > both.log 3>&1` wouldn't have the problem

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas All correct. Yes, and thanks for working out the `sh` variation. I will add it and explain it when my day job allows.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I just realised I don't fully understand the two separate instances of `3>&-` (closing fd 3). If you want to edit into my answer, go ahead, otherwise I'll let it stay as a comment.

Comment: Just closing it for those commands that don't need it. None of the commands need that fd 3 opened, it's just used here to pass the open file description on `both.log` to the left hand side of the pipe so the command group can have its stdout go there.